# Writing NSArray into plist

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, plist

I'm trying to save a `NSMutableArray` into a pre-existing plist.

When I try:

```
NSError *errorDesc;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSString *plistPath;
NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,  YES) objectAtIndex:0];
plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Array_Label_Generiche.plist"];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
   NSLog(@"prima volta");
   plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Array_Label_Generiche" ofType:@"plist"];
}
NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
NSMutableArray *temp = (NSMutableArray *)[NSPropertyListSerialization
                                                      propertyListFromData:plistXML
                                                      mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                                                      format:&format
                                                        errorDescription:&errorDesc];
if (!temp) {
  NSLog(@"Error reading plist: %@, format: %lu", errorDesc, format);
}

contatore = (int)temp.count ;

NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dictionary setObject:array_copiato forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text]];
NSDictionary *dictionary_da_salvare = [[NSDictionary alloc ] initWithDictionary: dictionary];

//AGGIUNGO I DATI CREATI
NSLog(@"TEMP %@",temp);
[temp addObject:dictionary_da_salvare];
BOOL didWriteArray = [temp writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
if (didWriteArray)
{
     NSLog(@"Write to .plist file is a SUCCESS!");
}
else
{
     NSLog(@"Write to .plist file is a FAILURE!");
}
```

In this case, output show me that "Write to .plist file is a FAILURE!".

In the Apple Guide, I read that I must serialize data before writing on the plist.

Then I tried to write these lines of code:

```
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:temp format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&errorDesc];
if(plistData == nil){
    NSLog (@"error writing to file: %@", errorDesc);
}
```

When I run the application, the output area reads:

> error writing to file: Property list invalid for format (property
>   lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFType')   Write to .plist file
>   is a FAILURE!

I think because the array test is NSMutableArray because I have read in the Apple Guide:

> The NSPropertyListSerialization class provides methods that convert
>   property list objects to and from several serialized formats. Property
>   list objects include NSData, NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary, NSDate,
>   and NSNumber objects. These objects are toll-free bridged with their
>   respective Core Foundation types (CFData, CFString, and so on).

Comment: temp array contains any data. Did you check properly??

Comment: Hello Hussain! I resolved my problem fortunately :) in my dictionary_da_salvare I had a property UIFont of label to save.

Comment: Hello Hussain! I resolved my problem fortunately :) in my dictionary_da_salvare I had a property UIFont of label to save.